# How to set Textarea maximum number of rows

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a Textarea that I use to display content only.

How do I set it it's maximum number of rows to 4, regardless of the string length.

Or is there a way to calculate amount of text that can fit in 4 rows on any device? I can use this to extract part of the string and set the text on the Textarea to this substring.

I have tried `textarea.setRows(4);`, but this seems to work only if I have to type in the text.

Comment: Codenameone Gui Builder https://www.codenameone.com, Cross-platform mobile application tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
textarea.setGrowLimit(4);
textarea.setRows(4);
textarea.setGrowByContent(false);
```

I'm not sure if grow limit is necessary once grow by content is disabled.

Comment: Thanks, both works individually. Is there a way to remove the constraint at runtime? I'm trying to simulate growShrink() when user tap `more`

Comment: I think setting grow by content to be true should work and setting grow limit to -1 should too.

Comment: I did that earlier, but `growShrink(200)` and `revalidate()` didn't work, only `forceRevalidate()` was effective.